Is learning to be a Salesforce Admin so necessary so that one to eventually become A salesforce Developer?
i am currently on a trail for admin intermediate. What advantage does pursuing this trail have as l eventualy wan to become a salesforce developer?

Hi and welcome to SFSE. If you read How to Ask you'll see that we like very specific questions that are not going to be opinion based. I would be surprised if you get a single, agreed answer to this question as it stands.

IMHO, no, you do not need to focus on admin learning to start developing. You will find that you do need to find your way around Setup and do some admin-based activities.

This is a really tricky question to answer because it depends on many factors, and it depends what value you want to add to your team, what your current role is, and how easily you think you'll get a job as a dev.
'Admin' is a very broad term.  There are definitely areas that you don't need to know as a dev.  On the other hand, if you don't know the basics on how to create objects, how fields and permissions work, how are you going to troubleshoot anything you build if there are bugs due to permissions?
As a junior dev, you're normally given the more basic tasks which usually include admin type tasks.  As you become more senior, your focus usually becomes more technical and specialised, which is where the admin skills are less relevant.
I tend to take a holistic approach. In smaller teams there is a project to deliver.  There's nothing worse than having team members that don't know the basics of how to make a system meet the business requirements.  If that requires admin skills, so be it.  If you can't do that, you're of no use to me.
In larger teams, the devs write code and there's usually some admins that do the rest.
On the other hand, is it reasonable to presume you'll get a job as a dev just because you've done the dev trailheads?  You normally need to prove yourself in some way, which is usually in a lower paying position such as a Salesforce admin.
I think there is definitely some value in obtaining admin skills. The hard part is defining what's the minimum required to get yourself into a position that you're employable as a dev.

As a future developer, here's something you'll want to learn: YAGNI (You Ain't Gonna Need It). While it is nice to be able to find where to create new tabs, customize applications, and check profile permissions, those are going to be very infrequent tasks. Most organizations you may one day work for already have Salesforce Administrators, and they get paid substantially less than you, the future developer, will. I've worked at organizations that literally forbid me from resetting users' passwords, not because of any security risk, but because it was literally burning money for the company when I could have been doing more profitable activities. If you want to learn Salesforce Administrator knowledge anyways, feel free! The more you know about Salesforce, the more opportunities you may find in the future. That said, if you're preparing for a future in Salesforce development, those admin trails are just a distraction. YAGNI.
